# Concerning this type of construct "They ran afoul of standards we'd like to see countries meet."

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> They ran afoul of **standards** we'd like to see countries *meet*.

*standards* is the object of *meet*,  it has been positioned six words before its verb, could someone please tell me how this procedure  is referred to (if it has any name) ?